# Backbone Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I am thinking of writing some online notes/book. Amongst other things, I want
to use Backbone to show different sections within a chapter as separate views. 
In other words, I want each chapter to behave like a single page application; 
different chapters will behave as separate single page applications. Within a chapter, as the user navigates from one section to another, I don't want the page to reload and am thinking of using the Backbone router to show these section views.

Please take a quick look at the code below and let me know if you see anything problematic with how I am using Backbone routing to render views.

The code works, but I want to know if I am doing anything inefficiently and if there are any "good practice" principles that I am violating. For example, I create new view instance every time the route changes. Is there a way to do this better?

```
(function() {
    var bApp = {
            model: {},
            view: {},
            collection: {},
            router: {}
        };

    window.bApp = bApp;

    bApp.view.section = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'div#chapter2',

        template: nunjucks.render('./client/views/client-templates/ch2_sec2.html'),


        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            return this;
        }

    });

    bApp.router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            '': 'showroute_ch2sec1',
            'ch2sec1': 'showroute_ch2sec1',
            'ch2sec2': 'showroute_ch2sec2'
        },

        showroute_ch2sec1: function() {
            section1 = new bApp.view.section;
            section1.template = nunjucks.render('./client/views/client-templates/ch2_sec1.html');
            section1.render();
        },

        showroute_ch2sec2: function() {
            section2 = new bApp.view.section;
            section2.template = nunjucks.render('./client/views/client-templates/ch2_sec2.html');
            section2.render();
        }

    });

    var r = new bApp.router;
    Backbone.history.start();


})();
```

Comment: Do you have a `<div id="chapter2">` in the DOM? Are you sure you want to render both views into the same element?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong title. The code works. I had chosen the title earlier when it was not working and then I got it to work. When I wrote the question above I forgot to change the title. My question is that since I am so new to Backbone I wanted to know whether there are any clearly "bad approaches" that I am using. The code, however, works.

Comment: @SeanVieira I was not aware of that site. Can you move the question there, or do I have to do it myself? Would appreciate instructions on how to do so, if I am supposed to do move it to that site.

Comment: @Curious2learn - unfortunately, I do not have the power to do this myself - I'll flag it for moderator attention and see if they can do it.

Comment: @SeanVieira: I flagged it too. I'll try to keep an eye on it and give it a review once it has moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few minor tweaks could help you out:

- Add a `close` method to all of your views, which cleans up your DOM, and unbinds any bound events (eg, with `this.stopListening()`). This will prevent 'zombie events' -- events bound to views which are no longer rendered.
- Move the logic for switching pages to a high-level application contoller. This will keep your router from getting too logic-heavy, and will allow the application controller to handle view creation and cleanup.

Here's how I might approach it.

```
// If all of your section views behave similarly
// why not create a single base class
bApp.view.Section = Backbone.View.extend({
 initialize: function(options) {
  this.template = options.template;
 },
 render: function() {
  var html = nunjucks.render(this.template);
  this.$el.html(html);
  return this;
 },
 close: function() {
  this.$el.empty();
  this.$el.off();
  this.stopListening();

  // Any other cleanup can go here...
 }
}); 

bApp.Router = Backbone.Route.extend({
 routes: {
  // Use route parameters, to simplify routing
  'book/:ch/:sec': 'navigateToSection'
 },

 navigateToSection: function(ch, sec) {
   // Delegate view-switching logic to application
   bApp.show(ch, sec);
 }
});

bApp.router = new bApp.Router();

// Give the bApp controller
// power over switching views
bApp.show = function(ch, sec) {
 var templatePath = './client/views/client-templates/ch' + ch + '_sec' + sec + '.html';

 if (this.currentView) {
  // Clean up your old view
  this.currentView.close();
 } 

 // render your new view
 this.currentView = new bApp.view.Section({
  el: 'div#chapter' + ch,
  template: templatePath 
 });

 this.currentView.render()

 // Update the route
 // This may seem redundant, but this will allow
 // you to call bApp.show() directly, and keep your
 // route up to date.
 bApp.route.navigate('book/' + ch + '/' + sec);
}
```

[Here's a good article by Derick Bailey about common pitfalls with Backbone routers.](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/)

I hope this is helpful!

**Edit: Clarify App/Router Separation**

Think of the router just as one of many ways to change the state of your application. Just like you could click a "first page" button to go to the first page, you could enter in `/page/first` in your browser to go to the first page. The only difference is whether your application state is bound to a button, or to a route.

This is the reason to keep the logic that changes the application state (ie. changing the rendered page) out of your router.

Consider this:

```
bApp.view.Section = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
  'change input.ch]': this.handlePageChange_
  'change input.sec]': this.handlePageChange_
 }
 //...
 handlePageChange_ = function() {
   var ch = this.$('input.ch').val();
   var sec = this.$('input.sec').val();

   // Let your application handle state change
   bApp.show(ch, sec)
 }
});
```

In this example, you've bound a input element to your application state, just as you bound a route to your application state. Either way, the state-changing logic belongs in your application controller.

Comment: edan, thanks a lot. This is really helpful. Being new to backbone there are a few things I need to figure out, but overall I understand what you are doing. The only part that is not clear is what you mean when you say that I will be able to call bApp.show() directly and about route being up to date. Is the explicit call to route.navigate an alternative to Backbone.history.start()?

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to say but I usually override `remove` rather than adding a `close`. @Curious2learn You'll still need the `Backbone.history.start()` call to crank up the routing machinery.